# Which developer set the precedent for use of the Shift key for safety (or skipping) at startup time?

Tags: history

### Which developer set the precedent?

I began wondering after recalling that Mozilla Firefox starts in safe mode if <kbd>Shift</kbd> is held at *application* startup time. Predecessors … I'm certain that Netscape Communications Corp didn't set the precedent, because the initial release of [Netscape Navigator](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Navigator) was in 1994.

For Apple Computer, Inc. and uses of <kbd>Shift</kbd> at or after *system* startup, the earliest references I can find are from **November 1991** and August 1992 (I began using Macs around January 1993). Respectively:

> … Peter Crownfiefd (via Zmac). …
>
> … discovered that holding down the Shift key during startup not only bypasses System extensions but also bypasses items in the Startup Items folder, if you want your extensions to load but not the files in the Startup Items folder, wait until all your extensions have loaded and you see the "Welcome to Macintosh" message and then press the Shift key. Continue holding down the Shift key until the desktop appears. …

– https://archive.org/stream/MacUser9111November1991/MacUser_9111_November_1991_djvu.txt

> … To block the opening of items in System 7’s Startup Items folder, press the shift key when the Finder’s menu titles first appear in the menu bar during start-up. To additionally inhibit the loading of extensions from the Extensions folder. Control Panels folder, and System Folder, press the shift key when the smiling Mac icon appears at the very beginning of the start-up sequence. You can release the shift key after the “Welcome to Macintosh” message appears. …

– https://archive.org/stream/MacWorld_9208_August_1992/MacWorld_9208_August_1992_djvu.txt

Did Apple set the precedent?

Comment: Migration is a good idea, I wasn't aware of the retro area. I ought to look to see whether there's already a question re: other, older keys; for this question I'm interested in the Shift key.

Comment: @nohillside re: the Shift key, I can't see anything comparable in the retro area. Would you like to migrate this question as is?

Comment: Apple IIgs System 6 added similar shift key startup functionality as of May 31st, 1991 (System 6 wasn't released until 1992). MacOS 7 was released in early May 1991, so presumably that was their inspiration.

Comment: Shift actually does the opposite on Acorn BBCs and Electrons; it means load what's on disk after completing startup — i.e. load more, not less.

Comment: @KelvinSherlock would you like to make that an answer? With or without a reference, it's useful. Thanks.

Comment: Back in the mid 1990s I used to do this when writing desktop Windows apps in VB - add a small delay to the loading splash screen and check to see if shift is held to then enable additional funcionality - and I must have got the idea from somewhere, but can't remember where from (and I wasn't an Apple user, so it wasn't from their machines).

Comment: The "heritage" (you might say) of the idea goes way back:  Computer operating systems - especially including very early OSes that might better be in quotes "operating systems" - had boot up options like this - typically involving "shifting" console switches.  (If you don't mind me calling "flipping a switch" as a "shifted key" ... or a "shift key" for short ...)

Comment: Funny detail for the date November 1991: Atari TOS 2.06 introduced a full memory wipe if you hold (the right) Shift when rebooting by Ctrl-Alt-Delete.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're going to find a single origin of this idea. The precedent for similar features on Apple machines goes back to 1979 and the Apple ][+.

The <kbd>Reset</kbd> key on the Apple ][ was close to the <kbd>Return</kbd> key, and was hit accidently more often than was desirable. On the ][+, <kbd>Reset</kbd> by itself did nothing, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Reset</kbd> reset the machine.

This was extended on the //e in 1983: <kbd>Open-Apple</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Reset</kbd> did a cold start with a self-test. The <kbd>Open-Apple</kbd> key later turned into the familiar clover-leaf key of present-day Apple machines.

Comment: The need to use Ctrl-Reset (instead of plain Reset) was introduced with the Apple II+, in 1979.

Comment: @cjs: Thanks, added.

Comment: Only 2 years later, the BBC Micro was checking the shift and control keys at reset time, too, as already noted.  But both of those are eclipsed by the minicomputers preceding them that checked the states of front panel switches at start-up, and performed different types of bootstraps accordingly.

Comment: @cjs: I remember a magazine article talking about how to modify an Apple II to behave in such a fashion; I don't know whether it came before or after the Apple II+, but if memory serves, it involved moving the low-side connection of the reset button to the control-key signal, with no need to add any components.